# Laravel - Bouncer generating a lot of models

Tags: laravel

I have got the task to maintain some legacy code made in Laravel. It is using Bouncer for access control. The application has serious performance problems, which I am analyzing. It uses Nova for GUI.

When I am using the Laravel Debugbar I can see, that certain calls generate over 33.000 models of (bouncer) abilities, for generating a list of 25 real world objects. The database **abilities** table contains only 113 row.

Is this what I have to expect?
If not, is there a source explaining the pitfalls of using Bouncer?

The [documentation](https://github.com/JosephSilber/bouncer) and the blog posts on Bouncer, don't touch the topic.

The code has the simplest implementation of Bouncer.

```php
use Silber\Bouncer\Database\HasRolesAndAbilities;
class User extends Authenticatable implements CanResetPassword, Auditable
{
    ...
    use HasRolesAndAbilities;
    ...
}
```

No use of Bouncer::allow() etc.

The code also generates too may SQL calls. I the call mentioned above Laravel Debugbar reports:

*152 statements were executed, 143 of which were duplicated, 9 unique.*

Comment: I used bouncer in the past. From what I recall, only 2 SQL queries should correspond to bouncer. (One for abilities and one for forbidden abilities). Check the debugbar to see which queries are marked as duplicates.

Comment: Hi. I'm the creator of Bouncer. It sounds like these queries are _probably_ not being done by Bouncer, but I'd be happy to help you be certain about that. Could you please open an issue on Bouncer, so that we can track it down?

Comment: Hi @JosephSilber, you are right. The former programmers had overdone the use of Bouncer totally. I make an answer to my own question below.

Answer (score 1):

The former programmers had used Bouncer, not only to limit the access of certain pages/models, but also to restrict the access to every field in those models. And fields of related models too.

After cleaning the code, the problem has disappeared.

Comment: Glad to hear :)